Transformer dot convention
If both input and output voltages are in phase, both dots will be shown up.
If the voltages are out of phase, the second dot will be shown down.
But how can the voltages be exactly in phase or exactly 180o out of phase?
Say the input voltage is \$v(t) = \sin(t) \$.
Then the input current will be \$i(t) = \sin(t- {\pi \over 2}) = -\cos(t)\$.
Output voltage will be \$v(t) = -L\,{di\over dt} = -L\,{d \over dt}(-\cos t) = -sin(t)\$.
So here the output voltage is 180o out of phase to the input voltage.
This doesn't look correct, because I feel the phase should depend on load and various other factors. It cannot be exactly 0 or 180o, can it?


It just marks the turn direction and sometimes the "hot end", which produces more EMI radiation.

There is an error in your math. The primary current is not minus cos. In other words the differential of sin is cos and not -cos.

There is another factor called mutual inductance M for which the dots are used. You seem to have omitted mutual inductance.

Also, your calculations are based on a perfect resistive load, something I have yet to encounter in my 55 year engineering career.  (Think about filter design.)

The dots are not there to assert what the phase relationship is to any precision, they are there to tell you how the transformer has been wound, how the wires are identified, whether the phase is roughly 0 or approximately 180 degrees.
If the transformer is ideal, then the phase relationships are 0 and 180 degrees.
You are correct that in a real transformer, finite primary inductance, non-zero leakage inductance and winding resistance (to name just a few non-idealities, there are many more!) make the phases deviate from the ideal 0 or 180 degrees.

This is an interesting question and it's really something that I don't think about too often.
For the sake of ideal conditions, these dots would represent an exact 0 or 180 degree difference in voltage between primary and secondary.
However, realistically, you are correct to be skeptical about this. Imperfections like inductor windings, leakages/parasitics, load impedances, etc. would indeed prevent an exact 0 or 180 degree difference.
The reason behind this can extremely meticulous, difficult to predict, and can exhibit chaotic behavior because of entropy.
But to answer your question about why 180 degrees out of shift instead of say, 90 degrees: this is because the current lags the voltage by 90 degrees, and the time derivative of the current introduces another 90-degree phase shift, leading to a total 180-degree phase shift between the input and output voltages. So your math is indeed correct.


I feel the phase should depend on load and various other factors.

Have you looked at the equivalent circuit for a non-ideal transformer? This one (from my basic website) is for a low-frequency transformer: -

As you can see there are several parasitic components that can affect the phase of the output voltage (especially under load). Once your transformer is required to operate in the kHz (and above) region, then there are inter-winding capacitance and winding self-capacitance to also consider. I suggest you try and model a non-ideal transformer using a simulator and play around with values to see what happens.

Two things:

We model an ideal transformer, so there are no extenuating circumstances; the signal is right-side-up or upside-down.
For any signal, a 180° phase shift is exactly an inversion, even if other angles don't make sense (the waveform is different).  It's a special case, whereas angle in general is a continuum value.

In the nonideal case, even if there are other phase angles (due to source/load impedance, and the transformer's inductance), the inversion still goes through 180 degrees.
In the further nonideal case where the transformer has capacitance (or even more generally still, transmission line characteristics), the capacitance between primary and secondary terminals (and nearby turns) can give a phase lead in one orientation, and a phase lag in the other; in this case, the inversion might give less than 180°.  In one limiting case, say at 90°, we have less a transformer and more a 90° hybrid network.

In a good transformer, primary and secondary winding mostly share the magnetic flux running through them.  The magnetic flux running through them creates voltage, and the created voltage at the dots shares the sign.
When the transformer is unloaded, this inductive voltage will rise to the input voltage since the magnetic flux rises until it does.  So the induced voltage on the secondary coil will share the sign according to the dots.
Once you factor in loads and all the realities of an unideal transformer, phases of the input and output voltages become more complex.  However, those voltage components caused by the shared part of the magnetic flux will still be in phase.  Components from unshared magnetic flux and from wire resistance can be out of phase, but as long as the transformer is largely operating within its specs, those will be minor in size.


But how can the voltages be exactly in phase or exactly 180o out of phase?

Let me point out that this is merely a symbol in a schematic diagram.  There's no reason to expect the kind of precision you're asking about in a schematic symbol.
The resistor symbol does not imply the inductance you'll have in a wirewound part and its lack in parts made of different materials; the capacitor symbol does not imply the different leakage resistance you'll have with parts made from different materials; the NPN and PNP transistor symbols don't imply the different base-to-emitter conduction voltage in parts made from germanium vs. silicon, a SPDT switch symbol doesn't convey whether the contacts are make-before-break or break-before-make.
And the dots on transformer symbols don't imply the phase relationships between winding are precisely 0 or 180 degrees.  Only that the gross phase relationship is approximately 0 or 180.
Schematic symbols convey the basic function of the component, closer to the characteristics of an ideal component, not the subtle variations that exist in the real world.  It's good to be aware of how the transformer windings will behave in a real circuit.  It's just unrealistic to expect the schematic symbol will express real-world behavior rather than ideal behavior.
